# Stochastic differential equation and generalization to more dimensions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Given deterministic functions of one variable $f(t)$ and $g(t)$, the stochastic differential equation
$$
dX= f(t) X dt + g(t) X dW
$$
has the following solution:
$$
X(t) = \exp \left \{ \int_0^t f(s) - \frac{1}{2}g(s)^2ds + \int_0^t g(s) dW \right \}, \ \ \ t > 0.
$$
I would like to know if this solution can be generalized to the following stochastic differential equation:
$$
dX = F(t) X dt + G X dW,
$$
where $X \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and $F(t), G \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and importantly $dW$ is still 1-dimensional.

Would the solution be simply
$$
\tag{1} X(t) = \exp \left \{ \int_0^t F(s) - \frac{1}{2}G^2ds + \int_0^t G dW \right \} \ ?
$$
If not, would it be possible to somehow generalize a $1$-d solution to $n$-d solution given that $dW$ is still $1$-d?

**Edit:**
As pointed out in the comments, the LHS of (1) is a vector, and the RHS of (1) is a matrix. A naive fix to this issue could be treating the RHS of (1) as an "evolution" operator applied to some initial condition vector $X_0 \in \mathbb{C}^n$ like so:
$$
\tag{2} X(t) = \exp \left \{ \int_0^t F(s) - \frac{1}{2}G^2ds + \int_0^t G dW \right \} X_0.
$$

Comment: The last formula cannot work, since you have a vector on the left-hand side and a matrix (exponential) on the right-hand side. You need to use the multidimensional Itô's formula.

Comment: @Abezhiko thanks for pointing this out. I have edited the question so that LHS and RHS are consistent.

Comment: There is little chance it works easily, because matrix exponential cannot be differentiated in the same manner as the scalar case (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map). As said, you need to recast you SDE in order to use the multidimensional Itô's lemma (https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17992/multidimensional-itos-lemma-for-vector-valued-functions).